# Updating column based on a group by and then other condition

Tags: sql, oracle

My purpose of this is to identify duplicate records based on same values in columns.

```
update table1
set reason = 'duplicate'
where id exists in (select min(id)
                    from table 1
                    where company ='Bestbuy'
                    and account = '123456'
                    group by company, account, date, price, member_id, amount)
and company = 'Bestbuy'
and account = '123456'
```

So this would group all the duplicate records together and update a column "reason" to say it is a duplicate. I am now trying to address a situation where I could group by all these columns, but I only want to "exclude" records if, lets say, the "sales rep" is different.

So with this example table:

[image: table]

So for example, the 1st,4th,5th,9th, and 10th would be grouped together on Company, Account, Date, Price, and member_ID. The sales rep would change, though. I am trying to create a sub group I guess based on the first group by, which will update the records in the group that have different sales reps.

So in the end, the 10th record would be excluded.

Comment: It is unclear what you want. So Dan should have 5 records which are not duplicates, but the one record from Kim is a duplicate? Are all 5 records from Dan duplicates, or only 4 of them? If only 4, is the Kim record then also a duplicate? What is your desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want :

```
update table1
         set reason = 'duplicate'
where exists (select 1
              from table1 t1 
              where t1.company = table1.company and 
                    t1.account = table1.account and
                    t1.date = table1.date and 
                    t1.price = table1.price and
                    t1.member_id =  table1.member_id and
                    t1.amount = table1.amount and
                    t1.sales_rep <> table1.sales_rep
             ) and 
      company = 'Bestbuy' and 
      account = '123456';
```